# How do i merge unallocated space with existing patition which are not in sequence?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

This is my partition table:

[image: partition table]

How can I merge or resize my existing partition `/dev/sda9` (and `/dev/sda9` is my Ubuntu 14.04) with unallocated space? I don't want to lose my data.

I have tried to resize `/dev/sda9` partition but I am getting any free space as shown no leading free space:

[image: image 2]

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8` to the front in order to be able to merge the unallocated space.

Be aware that moving partitions is time consuming. They will be copied/moved sector by sector. Make sure you don't interrupt the process once started. Be aware that moving partitions might interfere with your boot manager settings and other tools within your boot sequence. You might have to tweak things here and there.

Make a backup of the drive in to ensure you don't loose any data. Moving partitions around should be save.